# comparing multiple images

Tags: matlab, file-io, comparison

I have written a matlab function that enables me to get the name of image from user and compare it with the existing images and display if it matches or not..

```
function matchin
handles = guidata(gcbo);
set(handles.h_text,'String','performing matching...');
[image1, pathname]= uigetfile('*.bmp','Open An Fingerprint image');
Directory = fullfile ('F:','matlab','bin');
D = dir(fullfile(Directory,'*.bmp'));
set(handles.h_text,'String','matching complete....');
for i = 1:numel(D)
   if strcmp(image1,D(i).name)
       disp('matched');
   else       
        disp('not matched');
   end

end
```

the above code checks if the file name exists but i now want to compare the images itself instead of the file name. How can I do that?Please help..

Regards

Priya

Comment: you want to compare only the *name* and see if it exists in the folder?

Comment: yes..i just want to check if there is an image with the name given by the user..

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Is it possible to compare the images itself instead of the file name alone. How can I compare two images using the above mentioned code?

Comment: for this you have to follow different logic. You can use the `isequal` function in matlab. More info you can find [here](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/matlab/ref/isequal.html)

Comment: isequal() function is not a good option I think. Is there any other good mechanism to compare two images?

Comment: `dif = img1 - img2;` and you get the difference image. you can normalize it and view it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `strcmp` instead of `==` to compare strings of unknown lengths. You can change the `for loop` to:

```
D = dir(Directory);
for i = 1:numel(D)
   if strcmp(image1,D(i).name)
       disp('matched');
   else
       disp('not matched');
   end
end
```

Comment: this is one thing, the other thing is that right now `imcell` is just a cell array of empty cells.

Comment: >> matchin
not matched
not matched
not matched

ans =

min1.bmp

Comment: @George doesn't imcell contain 1-n files present in the folder?

Comment: I didn't know `cell` function before but it seems that it creates a list of empty cells. See my answer and tell me if it works for you

Comment: I updated my answer to include the list of files in the directory.  Looks like George has it too!

Comment: but i am getting the image i selected as 'ans' in the command window..how can i stop that from displaying??

Comment: That's because your function returns image1.  Either call the function with a semicolon (matchin;) of don't have it return anything.

Comment: Your function, as written above, returns image1.  That's what function image1=matchin means.  What do you mean it's not working?

Comment: it returns image1..are you suggesting that i should write the function as:function matchin; instead of function image1=matchin; ??

Comment: I am sorry..I now only understood what you meant..Thanks for the immediate response..it worked.

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Is it possible to compare the images itself instead of the filename alone. How cCan I compare two images using the above mentioned code?

Answer (score 1):

Your function should be something like this:

```
function image1=matchin

[image1, pathname]= uigetfile('*.bmp','Open An Fingerprint image');
Directory = fullfile ('F:','matlab','bin');
D = dir(fullfile(Directory,'*.bmp'));
imcell = {D.name}';
for i = 1:numel(D)
  if strcmp(image1,imcell{i})
  disp('matched');
else
    disp('not matched');
  end
end

end
```

you get the name of every file using `{D.name}'`. That's how it works for me at least when I tried it in a folder with images.

Comment: oh wow!!This works..thank you so much..it works perfectly!!Is there a possibility that i van display the result of this function in a text box in my GUI??

Comment: most probably yes, something like `mTextBox = uicontrol('style','text')` and 
`set(mTextBox,'String','Hello World')`... You can search [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/154660)